# How to persist Button.Pressed state in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new with Xamarin.Android, faced with small problem.

I want to stay pressed state in button after click and that's my code:

```
firstSelectButton.Click += FirstSelectButton_Click;  

private void FirstSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstSelectButton.Pressed = true;
    secondSelectButton.Pressed = false
}
```

But it doesn't work. I know about `setPressed` properties in native Android, but couldn't find the same in Xamarin.

Comment: Can you elaborate what does not work? Did `Pressed` property not update? Button's Visual State did not change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the `Button` android will automatically reset the `Pressed` state.

You can use `Touch` event to get around this issue, ex:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
button.Touch += (s, e) => {
    if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down) {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up) {
        e.Handled = false;
    }

    button.Pressed = !button.Pressed;

    e.Handled = true;
};
```

As you can see the code is kind of messy, so I would recommend you to use the `ToggleButton` instead of `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this 
[setSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelected(boolean))

In Xamarin, I think you could simply call button.Selected = true, also set state_selected attribute in your selector.xml file